# calling action helper in a plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my controller/action, I can call an action helper

```
$this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
```

I want to do the same thing in a plugin, so I tried this but it doesn't work. How can a plugin access an action helper?

```
$controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$controller->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
```

Comment: he's trying to achive the same thing ( disable layout in a pluggin ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670633/how-to-disable-layout-inside-a-plugin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method `getControllerName` return controller's name, not object. In the front controller plugin, you don't have access to controller object.

If you wanna access action helper in plugin, you should use [`Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) and its `getStaticHelper()` method:

> There are also two static methods for retrieving helpers from the helper broker: getExistingHelper() and getStaticHelper(). getExistingHelper() will retrieve a helper only if it has previously been invoked by or explicitly registered with the helper broker; it will throw an exception if not. getStaticHelper() does the same as getExistingHelper(), but will attempt to instantiate the helper if has not yet been registered with the helper stack. getStaticHelper() is a good choice for retrieving helpers which you wish to configure.

So your code should look like:

```
$layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Layout');
$layout->disableLayout();
```